# Socket can't accept connections when non-blocking?

Tags: c++, sockets, nonblocking, vxworks

EDIT: Messed up my pseudo-coding of the accept call, it now reflects what I'm actually doing.

I've got two sockets going. I'm trying to use send/recv between the two. When the listening socket is blocking, it can see the connection and receive it. When it's nonblocking, I put a busy wait in (just to debug this) and it times out, always with the error `EWOULDBLOCK`. Why would the listening socket not be able to see a connection that it could see when blocking?

The code is mostly separated in functions, but here's some pseudo-code of what I'm doing.

```
int listener = -2;
int connector = -2;
int acceptedSocket = -2;

getaddrinfo(port 27015, AI_PASSIVE) results loop for listener socket
{
  if (listener socket() == 0)
  {
    if (listener bind() == 0)
      if (listener listen() == 0)
        break;
    listener close(); //if unsuccessful
  }
}
SetBlocking(listener, false);


getaddrinfo("localhost", port 27015) results loop for connector socket
{
  if (connector socket() == 0)
  {
    if (connector connect() == 0)
      break; //if connect successful
    connector close(); //if unsuccessful
  }
}

loop for 1 second
{
  acceptedSocket = listener accept();
  if (acceptedSocket > 0)
    break; //if successful
}
```

This just outputs a huge list errno of `EWOULDBLOCK` before ultimately ending the timeout loop. If I output the file descriptor for the accepted socket in each loop interation, it is never assigned a file descriptor.

The code for SetBlocking is as so:

```
int SetBlocking(int sockfd, bool blocking)
{
  int nonblock = !blocking;

  return ioctl(sockfd,
    FIONBIO,
    reinterpret_cast<int>(&nonblock));
}
```

If I use a blocking socket, either by calling `SetBlocking(listener, true)` or removing the `SetBlocking()` call altogether, the connection works no problem.

Also, note that this connection with the same implementation works in Windows, Linux, and Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the tight loop you are not letting the OS complete your request. That's the difference between VxWorks and others - you basically preempt your kernel.

Use `select(2)` or `poll(2)` to wait for the connection instead.

Comment: Basically, I've written a cross-platform sockets wrapper for 17 different OSes, and I'm running the same unit tests on all platforms. This is to test solely the functionality of a non-blocking socket, in the case that one of my end-users would like to use a blocking socket for whatever reason. I understand that busy-waiting is entirely suboptimal (at best), but there are legitimate reasons to use non-blocking sockets. Anyways, how then would you recommend I unit test a non-blocking socket? Actually, how would I use a non-blocking socket in general (i.e. avoid preempting the kernel)?

Comment: Getting `EWOULDBLOCK` from `accept(2)` on a non-blocking socket is probably enough of a unit-test.

Comment: Yet it passes on the other operating systems. Essentially, my wrapper is to achieve the same functionality across operating systems. Since nonblocking sockets are far more different than expected, I'm considering removing nonblocking from this wrapper and writing a separate wrapper for nonblocking sockets and all their little nuances. Is this the route you would recommend, or would there be a way to have VxWorks not pre-empt the kernel in this loop?

Comment: The thing is that tight loop is never (well, almost never) a working scenario for non-blocking sockets. Test it with `select(2)`, `poll(2)` on all platforms, with `epoll(7)` on Linux, with `kqueue(2)` on BSDs and OSX. Don't know if VxWorks provides anything special like that.